# local storage : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript

[image: Пример кода js]

[image: в local storage данные есть]

В чем же ошибка ? При том, что данные "ross" ,были введены и отображаются.

```
var myButton = document.querySelector('button');
var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
function setUserName() {
  var myName = prompt('Please enter your name.');
  localStorage.setItem('name', myName);
  myHeading.innerHTML = 'Mozilla is cool, ' + myName;
}

if(!localStorage.getItem('name')) {
  setUserName();
} else {
  var storedName = localStorage.getItem('name');
  myHeading.innerHTML = 'Mozilla is cool, ' + storedName;
}

myButton.onclick = function() {
  setUserName();
}
```

вот полный код скрипта

Comment: у вас нет h1 в разметке

Comment: Спасибо! Так и не было. все заработало.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> У Вас отcутствует тег `h1` в `html` разметке.
>
> Это можно понять из сообщения об ошибке и вашего кода:

В самом начале Вы делаете поиск первого попавшегося `h1` на странице

```
var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
```

А затем этому элементу пытаетесь изменить свойство:

```
myHeading.innerHTML = 'Mozilla is cool, ' + storedName;
```

При всем этом отладчик Вам сказал, что он не может поменять свойство `innerHTML`  у объекта, который `null`;

Если учесть то, что нигде больше изменения значения переменной `myHeading` не происходит, можно сделать вывод что `document.querySelector` не нашел то, что искал.

Answer (score 1):

Вам же ошибка говорит что `NULL`, и что скрип не может установить `NULL`.

```js
const body = document.querySelector('body')
let name = prompt('Ok?');
console.info(name);
body.innerHTML = `<p>${name}</p>`;
```

> **UPD** Как верно подметили в комментарии, проверьте, что нашелся элемент, в который вы вставляете данные.